# How to update a sum field without using aggregation on save?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models as following:

```
Foo(models.Model):
    total = models.IntegerField()

Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    number = models.Interger()
```

and what is the best solution to update total field which is the sum of numbers in Bar model when I'm saving the Foo model?

I've tried overriding the save method on Foo model, and because Bar wasn't saved yet it didn't calculate the recent numbers(I should have saved twice)

Comment: Please clarify what you want to count. Is it a sum of the numbers of all instances of the `Bar` class with a foreign key relationship to the instance of the `Foo` class being saved?

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: Currently I'm using Bar model post_save signals, but there should be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your original idea of overriding save should work. If it's to operate when a `Foo` instance saves then something along the lines of:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.total = sum([x.number for x in self.bar_set.all()])
    super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you want the total to update each time a relevant `Bar` instance is saved then you should instead do a similar override on the `Bar` class:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Bar, self).save(*args, **kwargs)        
    self.foo.total = sum([x.number for x in self.foo.bar_set.all()])
    self.foo.save()
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't unless I hit save twice.

Comment: That's how I did it using signals. But overriding the save method on Bar without using signals is a better and simpler idea.